# Running a certain TestNG test group with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

Is it possible to let IntelliJ IDEA (13.1) run tests of a certain [TestNG test group](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups)? How?

The only sultion I've found so far is running the tests with Maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you able to set up a `TestNG` run configuration and try ticking the `Group` radio button, as per the image below?

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/70/TestNG/tngRunConfig.gif

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for, even though it is not possible to set more than one group in IntelliJ.

Comment: Super. You can always "chain" run configurations via the "Before Launch:" -> "Run another Configuration" feature

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: does this help? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-testng.html

Comment: @vikingsteve - Could you please help me in this related question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388561/intellij-idea-how-to-run-specific-testng-groups-in-a-class