# Intellij IDEA - How to run specific testng groups in a class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a maven java project in the latest Intellij IDEA with Testng plugin. I want to run specific groups in a test class without manually creating an xml config file for this.

Can I do that through the run configuration menu instead ? Unfortunately, the menu only lets me select groups, classes, methods etc. but not the groups inside a particular class.

Comment: Are you able to right click on the specific group in the code window, does it have an option there to make a test?

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you have the following code sample:

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class Test1 {
  @Test(groups = { "functest", "checkintest" })
  public void testMethod1() {
  }

  @Test(groups = {"functest", "checkintest"} )
  public void testMethod2() {
  }

  @Test(groups = { "functest" })
  public void testMethod3() {
  }
}
```

To run only *checkintest* group go to ***Run Configuration***, create new TestNG config -> select Test kind "Group" -> select *checkintest* group. 
Only testMethod1, testMethod2 will be run.